# How to set border edges in HorizontalBarChartView

Tags: ios, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

I need help creating this style BarChart, only the rounded end edges.

Here is an example:
[image]

I'm using the library "ios-charts" but it does not have this feature. Please let me know how to do this - rounded end edges and horizontal bar chart with negative values.

Comment: If you want a recommendation for a specific library, [Stack Exchange Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is probably the best place to do it.

Comment: thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use also SwiftCharts - https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts there's an example with a similar chart, and adjust the bar views accordingly (using e.g. Stefan's answer). Here you can see how to use custom views: https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/Examples/BarsExample.swift and here how to use +/- bars: https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/Examples/BarsPlusMinusWithGradientExample.swift

Answer (score 0):

It's not that that hard to draw bars that like that yourself. Perhaps fork that library and improve it and make a push request. Here's some simple code that draws a red bar pointing to the right.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundedBarView: UIView {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let color = UIColor.redColor()
    let barRect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
    var rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: barRect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.TopRight | UIRectCorner.BottomRight, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(barRect.height/2.0, barRect.height/2.0))
    rectanglePath.closePath()
    color.setFill()
    rectanglePath.fill()
}
```

}